# Are the Upapuranas supposed to be part of the Mahapuranas?

Tags: puranas, vyasa, upapuranas

The Upanishads are supposed to be part of the Vedas. Are the Upapuranas supposed to be the same and be part of the Mahapuranas? Did they get separated due to convenience or controversy of the real system or something else?

Comment: There is no connection whatsoever between Mahapuranas and Upapuranas like there is between Vedas and Upanishads. BTW the Q would have made more sense if used the example of Upavedas and Vedas instead of Upanishads and Vedas

Comment: @Rickross That might just be because the placement of the Upanishads is not going to be controversial. Can you imagine how many people would get irrationally angry if an Upapurana from a "different sect" is supposed to be in a Mahapurana they like?

Comment: @Rickross Also some of them might not even be real Puranas. For example, the Kalki Purana seems as though it should be part of the Mahabharata as the Yuga Gandharvas are really important to its plot and Satya is missing (and Treta, but he is missing everywhere).

Comment: @Rickross Maybe that is the point of the Harivamsha, to reveal who Treta is and tell his origin story because as it stands the Harivamsha doesn't fit in well with the rest of the Mahabharata.